# How to call ASM functions with structs

Tags: assembly, winapi, struct, x86-64, nasm

I don't know how works structures functions with nasm if someone can explain me, I tried with struc and other like %define but I think I don't have the good syntax. In my code I need that structure :

```
typedef struct _SYSTEM_INFO {
  union {
    DWORD dwOemId;
    struct {
      WORD wProcessorArchitecture;
      WORD wReserved;
    } DUMMYSTRUCTNAME;
  } DUMMYUNIONNAME;
  DWORD     dwPageSize;
  LPVOID    lpMinimumApplicationAddress;
  LPVOID    lpMaximumApplicationAddress;
  DWORD_PTR dwActiveProcessorMask;
  DWORD     dwNumberOfProcessors;
  DWORD     dwProcessorType;
  DWORD     dwAllocationGranularity;
  WORD      wProcessorLevel;
  WORD      wProcessorRevision;
} SYSTEM_INFO, *LPSYSTEM_INFO;`
```

Here's my asm code with nasm in x64, I let [sysinfo] in my code without define It, all of register contain correct value it just missing the function structure :

```
section .data

section .bss

section .text
    global main

main:
    ; Parse PEB and find kernel32
    xor rcx, rcx             ; RCX = 0
    mov rax, [gs:rcx + 0x60] ; RAX = PEB
    mov rax, [rax + 0x18]    ; RAX = PEB->Ldr
    mov rsi, [rax + 0x20]    ; RSI = PEB->Ldr.InMemOrder
    lodsq                    ; RAX = Second module
    xchg rax, rsi            ; RAX = RSI, RSI = RAX
    lodsq                    ; RAX = Third(kernel32)
    mov rbx, [rax + 0x20]    ; RBX = Base address           

   ; Parse kernel32 PE and find GetProcAddress
   xor r8, r8                 ; Clear r8
   mov r8d, [rbx + 0x3c]      ; R8D = DOS->e_lfanew offset
   mov rdx, r8                ; RDX = DOS->e_lfanew
   add rdx, rbx               ; RDX = PE Header
   mov r8d, [rdx + 0x88]      ; R8D = Offset export table
   add r8, rbx                ; R8 = Export table
   xor rsi, rsi               ; Clear RSI
   mov esi, [r8 + 0x20]       ; RSI = Offset namestable
   add rsi, rbx               ; RSI = Names table
   xor rcx, rcx               ; RCX = 0
   mov r9, 0x41636f7250746547 ; GetProcA

Get_Function:

   inc rcx                    ; Increment the ordinal
   xor rax, rax               ; RAX = 0
   mov eax, [rsi + rcx * 4]   ; Get name offset
   add rax, rbx               ; Get function name
   cmp QWORD [rax], r9        ; GetProcA ?
   jnz Get_Function

   xor rsi, rsi               ; RSI = 0
   mov esi, [r8 + 0x24]       ; ESI = Offset ordinals
   add rsi, rbx               ; RSI = Ordinals table
   mov cx, [rsi + rcx * 2]    ; Number of function

   xor rsi, rsi               ; RSI = 0
   mov esi, [r8 + 0x1c]       ; Offset address table
   add rsi, rbx               ; ESI = Address table

   xor rdx, rdx               ; RDX = 0
   mov edx, [rsi + rcx * 4]   ; EDX = Pointer(offset)
   add rdx, rbx               ; RDX = GetProcAddress
   mov rdi, rdx               ; Save GetProcAddress in RDI         

   ; Use GetProcAddress to find the address of LoadLibrary

   mov rcx, 0x41797261          ; aryA
   push rcx                     ; Push on the stack
   mov rcx, 0x7262694c64616f4c  ; LoadLibr
   push rcx                     ; Push on stack
   mov rdx, rsp                 ; LoadLibraryA
   mov rcx, rbx                 ; kernel32.dll base address
   sub rsp, 0x30                ; Allocate stack space for function call
   call rdi                     ; Call GetProcAddress
   add rsp, 0x30                ; Cleanup allocated stack space
   add rsp, 0x10                ; Clean space for LoadLibrary string
   mov rsi, rax                 ; LoadLibrary saved in RSI

   ; Use LoadLibrary to find the address of Kernel32.dll

   mov rcx, 0x6c6c642e           ; lld
   push rcx                      ; Push on the stack
   mov rcx, 0x32336c656e72654b   ; 23lenreK
   push rcx                      ; Push on stack
   mov rcx, rsp                  ; Kernel32.dll
   sub rsp, 0x20                 ; Allocate stack space for function call
   call rsi                      ; Call LoadLibraryA
   add rsp, 0x20                 ; Cleanup allocated stack space
   add rsp, 0x10                 ; Clean space for Kernel32.dll string
   mov r15, rax                  ; Base address of Kernel32.dll in R15

   ; Call GetProcAddress(Kerne32.dll, "GetSystemInfo")

   xor rcx, rcx                  ; RCX = 0
   push rcx                      ; Push 0 on stack
   mov rcx, 0x6f666e496d           ; ofnI
   push rcx                      ; Push on the stack
   mov rcx, 0x6574737953746547   ; metsySeG
   push rcx                      ; Push on stack
   mov rdx, rsp                  ; GetSystemInfo
   mov rcx, r15                  ; Kernel32.dll base address
   sub rsp, 0x28                 ; Allocate stack space for function call
   call rdi                      ; Call GetProcAddress
   add rsp, 0x28                 ; Cleanup allocated stack space
   add rsp, 0x18                 ; Clean space for GetSystemInfo string
   mov r14, rax                  ; GetSystemInfo in R14

   lea rcx, [sysinfo]
   call r14

   end:
   add rsp, 40
   ret
```

Here's my commands:

```
nasm -fwin64 shell.asm
link /out:shell.exe /subsystem:console /ENTRY:main /LARGEADDRESSAWARE:NO shell.obj kernel32.Lib msvcrt.lib User32.Lib WS2_32.Lib.
```

All registers contain correct value.
I also get this error in windbg :

```
KERNELBASE!GetSystemInfoInternal+0xf:
00000000`006fdee7 410f1100        movups  xmmword ptr [r8],xmm0 ds:ffffffff`ffffff78=????????????????????????????????
0:000> r
rax=0000000000000000 rbx=ffffffffffffff78 rcx=000000000018fe38
rdx=000000000018fe28 rsi=0000000000420800 rdi=0000000000000000
rip=00000000006fdee7 rsp=000000000018fd88 rbp=0000000000000000
 r8=ffffffffffffff78  r9=0000000000000000 r10=0000000000000000
r11=0000000000000246 r12=0000000000000000 r13=0000000000000000
r14=000000000041dec0 r15=0000000000400000
iopl=0         nv up ei pl zr na po nc
cs=0033  ss=002b  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00010246
KERNELBASE!GetSystemInfoInternal+0xf:
00000000`006fdee7 410f1100        movups  xmmword ptr [r8],xmm0 ds:ffffffff`ffffff78=????????????????????????????????
```